# Get a token by Github API

Tags: git, github, access-token, github-api

I manually created a token in `Github -> Settings -> Personal access tokens -> Generate new token` and chose only `repo` `scope`.

This token works fine, so with it I can push into organization I have `write` privileges.

Then I want to do the same (get an access_token) by `github-api`.

```python
params = dict(client_id=client_id,
              client_secret=client_secret,
              code=code)

url = url_concat("https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token", params)

req = HTTPRequest(url,
                  method="POST",
                  headers={"Accept": "application/json"},
                  body="")
```

As a result I have such `json`:

```json
{
    'scope': 'repo',
    'token_type': 'bearer',
    'access_token': 'xxxxxxxx10755fbb6c281e92902ed122144886c5'
}
```

It is as everything correct, but I can't push into organization repos where I have `write` privileges. I can push only into my own repos.

Could you help? Any idea where is a mistake or inaccuracy is welcome.

Comment: Your question is very vague. I've posted two possible solutions in my answer. If they're not correct, you will *really* need to update your question because there is too little detail.

Comment: Roma, can you take a look at my answer and let me know if you have other questions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So if you want to do this via GitHub's API, your request needs to change.

First you need to be using the [`/authorizations` endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/#create-a-new-authorization) like so:

```
POST /authorizations
Authorization: Basic ...
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: ...

{
  "scopes": [
    "repo",
    "write:org"
  ],
  "note": "Example from StackOverflow by @sigmavirus24",
  "client_id": "Your client_id here",
  "client_secret": "Your client_secret here",
  "fingerprint": "1234",
}
```

This should then return a `201 Created` response with a body like so:

```
{
  "id": 72249124,
  "url": "https://api.github.com/authorizations/72249124",
  "scopes": [
    "repo",
    "write:org"
  ],
  "token": "abcdefgh12345678",
  "token_last_eight": "12345678",
  "hashed_token": "25f94a2a5c7fbaf499c665bc73d67c1c87e496da8985131633ee0a95819db2e8",
  "app": {
    "url": "http://my-github-app.com",
    "name": "my github app",
    "client_id": "abcde12345fghij67890"
  },
  "note": "optional note",
  "note_url": "http://optional/note/url",
  "updated_at": "2017-02-08T20:39:23Z",
  "created_at": "2017-02-08T17:26:27Z",
  "fingerprint": "1234"
}
```

Except it will be real.

That said, it appears that you're trying to use the endpoint that allows GitHub to be used as an authentication provider. In other words, you're building an application that allows users to sign-in with GitHub. If that's the case, then you need to specifically follow the [Web Application Flow for OAuth](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#web-application-flow).

In that case, you're part of the way there but you're sending the wrong parameters.

First you make a GET request:

```
GET https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=<your-client_id>&scopes=repo%20write:org&state=something-random
```

Then you will receive data back from GitHub which you must use in your POST

```
POST https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token?client_id=<your-client_id>&client_secret=<your-client_secret>&code=<code-from-github>
Accept: application/json
```

After that, any request you make must have

```
Authorization: token <token-received-in-response-to-POST>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, I am a bit confused here. Wouldn't we require all the scopes for making the POST request for a new token with a specific scope.
How would one make a system where only email permission is asked during first sign up and say when the user tries to watch a repo then repo scope authorization is asked from the user. What am I missing?

Comment: The /authorizations endpoint was removed in Nov 2020. https://developer.github.com/changes/2/#deprecation-timeline

Answer (score 1):

use POST with the url https://api.github.com/authorizations by passing your `client_id` and `client_secret` in the **Basic Auth of Authorization**.
Send the remaining parameters in json format in body as raw.
e.g.:

```
{
  "scopes": 
    [
      "repo",
      "write:org"
    ],
  "note": "Sample Access Token using API Call",
  "fingerprint": "DEMO#$12@A"
}
```

Comment: The /authorizations endpoint was removed in Nov 2020 - https://developer.github.com/changes/2/#deprecation-timeline